# How can I automatically scrape new information from page with Facebook open graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi I have this problem with Facebook open graph API.

I know I can manually scrape new information about meta tags from a page with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/. But I'm trying to use api to do it automatically, but I just can't understand what is going on.

I stumbled across this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/. Can you guys tell me exactly what to type there to scrape new og meta tags?

For page: http://www.akademiaharmonia.pl/o-jodze.html

What I tried: in this Graph API Explorer I chose "POST" and added 2 fields:

```
id = http://www.akademiaharmonia.pl/o-jodze.html
scrape = true
```

I got this error:

```
{ 
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 104
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the graph explorer. Do a normal Curl query instead

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I tried using PHP Curl query before, but I got the same error. I decided to success with this graph explorer to understand why I get this error and how it works. Can you please tell me what I got wrong?

Comment: I read I don't need any authorization to do this. But It keeps asking me for a token. How to get this access token? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why but it works perfectly fine now. I also noticed that the graph explorer is now 2.1 instead of 2.0... hmm...